# How to use format function correctly

Tags: python

I've just finished typing up some code for a game I'm working on, however I need to use the "format" function to make the output align properly, I tried using it on this bit of code for example:

```
 print("    ",humanscore,"    -     ",compscore)
```

in order to make sure the values of the variables don't shift their position, but it comes up with an error saying "TypeError: format() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)", So basically I'm just wondering how you use the format function to align lines of code like this. (the spaces inbetween were a cheap way of aligning stuff without the format function. )

Comment: so... The example code you post doesn't have the `format` function in it.  Did you mean to type `format` instead of `print`?

Comment: well that's the code originally without any format function in it, I'm trying to understand how you apply it.

Comment: is that the actual code you are running that generates your error? It is n't clear, since you are asking about the `format` function but your example uses the `print` function...I am guessing `print` calls `format` which is unhappy about the extra parameters you passed `print`. Is that a good summary of your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
print("    {},   -     {}".format(humanscore, compscore))
```

Assuming your scores are variable and you have this in a for loop.

Comment: Note, It's probably unnecessary to call `str` on the inputs ... `format` should do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `format` method is called on a string and substitutes formatted quantities into the string at places you indicate with markers using braces (`{`,`}`).
There's a [whole mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to Python's new(er) string formatting, but for your purposes, to make the scores align you should decide how many characters the maximum score will take up and use `'{:<n>d}'` where `<n>` is that maximum. For example if you won't have (integer) scores higher than `999999`,

```
In [8]: humanscore1 = 12
In [9]: compscore1 = 933
In [10]: humanscore2 = 8872
In [11]: compscore2 = 12212

print('{:6d} - {:6d}'.format(humanscore1, compscore1))
print('{:6d} - {:6d}'.format(humanscore2, compscore2))
    12 -    933
  8872 -  12212
```

To center the numbers instead of aligning them to the right of their fields, use the `^` specifier:

```
print('{:^6d} - {:^6d}'.format(humanscore2, compscore2))
print('{:^6d} - {:^6d}'.format(humanscore1, compscore1))
 8872  - 12212 
  12   -  933
```